# Getting a System.NullPointerException: Attempt To De-reference A Null Object error

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm getting the mentioned error on the line that contains "modifiedUsers.add(u);" when executing this method through an after update trigger:

```
public static void MethodName(User[] newUsers, Map<id, user> oldUserMap){
    User[] modifiedUsers;

    for (User u : newUsers){
        User oldUser = oldUsermap.get(u.id);

        if ((u.field1__c != oldUser.field1__c)&&(u.field2__c == TRUE)){
            modifiedUsers.add(u); //ERROR HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know what it could be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You need to initialize the list before you can add elements on to it.

```
public static void MethodName(User[] newUsers, Map<id, user> oldUserMap){
List<User> modifiedUsers = new List<User>();

for (User u : newUsers){
    User oldUser = oldUsermap.get(u.id);

    if ((u.field1__c != oldUser.field1__c)&&(u.field2__c == TRUE)){
        modifiedUsers.add(u); //ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

}